# Is there a conventional way to support more than one release in git?

Tags: git, workflow, release-management

Is there a git workflow designed to maintain software from multiple git branches (e.g., release.1.1
branched from master long ago, and release.1.2 branched from master more recently).  Feature Branch
Workflow, Gitflow Workflow, and Forking workflow have great documentation but I haven't found
information about managing more than one release.

Managing multiple releases would require a process for applying hotfixes and feature to one or more 
release branches.  A master branch would be used to maintain all changes for future releases, the 
release closest to master might get some features and hotfixes, releases furthest would get the fewest 
updates, and the release furthest from master would be the first to reach end-of-life.

I'm thinking it would look something like

```
master -------+----------+----------+----------+------+-----------+--------------------
               \          \          \        /        \         /
                \          \          Hotfix-+          Feature-+
                 \          \                  Hotfix             Feature
                  \          release_1.2-------+------------------+---------------
                   \                             Hotfix
                    release_1.1------------------+----------------------End-Of-Life
```

The following is revised to look more like Git Flow, but with a 'release_1.1' branch.

```
                                          release_1.1---------+---------+---
                                          |                    \       /
                                          |                     Hotfix3             
                                          |
     tag 1.0     tag 1.0.1     tag 1.1  tag 1.1.1     tag 1.2  tag 1.2.1
       |           |             |        |             |        |
master +-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------+------------------
       |          /             /        /             /        /
       |         /             /        /             /        /
       \  Hotfix1             /  Hotfix2             /  Hotfix3        
release |        \       +-+-+          \       +-+-+          \
        |         \     /     \          \     /     \          \
develop +-+--------+---+-------+-+--------+---+-------+----------+------
           \          /           \          /
            FeatureA-+             FeatureB-+
```

Comment: are you looking for a, say, standard or suggested way to manage the release, or how to bring new changes (fixes/features) to other branches?

Comment: Looking for a standard or suggested way to manage releases using git to avoid Reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You mention Git Flow in your question. I wonder how it is insufficient for your needs? It seems to offer exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: Rather than being able to support multiple release, wouldn't it be more convenient to be able to release fast? If you have enough confidence in your automated tests so that you can release whenever you want within minutes (or hours), you'll likely never need two releases in parallel.

Comment: Git Flow is close, but I don't see how someone can get a hotfix without doing an upgrade.  For example, what if there is a major feature in master that requires a hardware upgrade (FeatureB), and a major security fix that is found after FeatureB is in master (Hotfix3).  I'm wondering if it's acceptable to go back and create a branch for release 1.1 and implement the security fix (Hotfix3), and maintain the branch until everyone has a chance to upgrade.

Comment: @gturri at an old work place the automated testing would take a couple of days to complete and the formal testing with humans would take 6 weeks or more.  That was after a lot of effort had gone in to make things faster.  I agree that faster releases with a single focus would be the ideal for a programmer but not all situations allow that.  Think about OS or bigger projects with an LTS and cutting edge trains.  What works for small project might not stretch to large ones well.  Do not forget there is always something larger than any of us have experienced/know about it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge a hotfix branch that is based on the current `master` back into older releases—this would introduce all changes from `master` into the older release as well.  So you have to choose a common ancestor of `master` and all release branches as the base for your hotfix branch, typically the point where the oldest revision you still want to support diverged from `master`.  From there on, for each release, (1) merge the hotfix branch into the release branch, and then (2) merge the point where the next release diverges from `master` into the hotfix branch and resolve the conflicts.  Finally, merge the hotfix branch back into `master`.

You may want to have a look at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

Comment: This is good information about merging, but doesn't address the question 'Is there a conventional way to support more than one release in git?'.  

But while on the topic of Hotfixes and merging, in most cases it's really not necessary to use merge for Hotfixes.  For example, if the security bug is:
    `print passwords`
and the fix is
    `if authorized:
      print passwords`
then merge is really not required to put this fix in multiple release branches.

Comment: Well, you could always cherry-pick the hotfixes back into the older revisions—but that wasnt't what you were expecting to hear, right?  I told you the most “conventional” approach of doing this with git.  Yes, this involves branching and merging, which shouldn't be a surprise as these are probably the two most distinguished features of git.  (No other SCM I know makes them as fast and painless.)  If your question was if there is a special git command to do that: no, as far as I know, there isn't.  This is the power of git: using just the basic commands, you can do basically anything you want.

Comment: Maybe I'm not asking the question clearly enough.  There's plenty of information on the web about merging, cherry-picking, patching, etc..  But this question relates to the state of a git repository for an application.  If there are users that need a hotfix or want a feature, but can't upgrade to the latest tag in master, is there a conventional method used to accommodate them.  I revised my workflow lanes to follow the Gitflow method, but with a release_1.1 branch to to provide Hotfix3 for users not able to upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: “If there are users that need a hotfix or want a feature, but can't upgrade to the latest tag in master, is there a conventional method used to accommodate them.” — Sure, that's exactly what I described.

Comment: Cool, so it's acceptable to create a release_x.x branch from a tag x.x.x in master and keep that branch active with Hotfixes and possibly features until all users have upgraded to a newer release.

Comment: There was a chap at where I use to work that would generate all fixes on the oldest supported branch.  This was in BitKeeper but perhaps a similar thing would work in Git.  He would commit the fix in the old branch then merge it through each active branch until he reached the current one.  He would push it to the current branch and then discard the change from the earlier ones.  This gave him a fix that had an old origin which was easier to apply to an old repo if needed.  If you didn't do this you had to do a plain text patch to the old branches.